# Change dateTimeLabelFormats dynamically based on time selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

For me, dateTimeLabelFormats showing inconsistent date-format based on the time selection.

Below is the URL

```
http://jsfiddle.net/46bk7pvm/2/
```

In above URL, when I select 6 month it is reflecting with proper date format. Which is `'%Y-%m'`. But when I select 1 Month or 3 Months it is reflecting with  day: `'%Y<br/>%m-%d'`, format. But it should be Month format which is `month: '%Y-%m'`.

In short for month selection it should be

```
month: '%Y-%m',
```

for day selection it should be

```
day: '%Y<br/>%m-%d',
```

and for year it should be

```
year: '%Y'
```

Here is the code block

```
Highcharts.stockChart('container', {

    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        dateTimeLabelFormats: {
            second: '%Y-%m-%d<br/>%H:%M:%S',
            minute: '%Y-%m-%d<br/>%H:%M',
            hour: '%Y-%m-%d<br/>%H:%M',
            day: '%Y<br/>%m-%d',
            week: '%Y<br/>%m-%d',
            month: '%Y-%m',
            year: '%Y'
        }
    },

    rangeSelector: {
        selected: 1
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'USD to EUR',
        data: usdeur
    }]
});
```

How can we set above dateformat dynamically based on the time period selection.?

Comment: Please include all relevant code within your question, don't just link to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`dateTimeLabelFormats`](https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.dateTimeLabelFormats) defines format for xAxis ticks according to the **distance** between closest of them. When you click `1M`, then you have only four weeks of data so if there will be room only for four dataLabels then `week` format will be applied. If you have more space (wider chart) then `day` format will be used etc.

What you want is probably to change format on labels after button click: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/wxpfc2k5/

Snippet (only 1M button!):

```
rangeSelector: {
  selected: 1,
  buttons: [{
    type: 'month',
    count: 1,
    text: '1m',
    events: {
      click: function() {
        chart.xAxis[0].update({
          labels: {
            format: '{value:%Y-%m}' // change format on click
          }
        });
      }
    }
  }, {
    type: 'month',
    count: 3,
    text: '3m'
  }, {
    type: 'month',
    count: 6,
    text: '6m'
  }, {
    type: 'ytd',
    text: 'YTD'
  }, {
    type: 'year',
    count: 1,
    text: '1y'
  }, {
    type: 'all',
    text: 'All'
  }]
}
```

More about label formatting can be found in the [API](https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.labels.format) and [docs](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/labels-and-string-formatting).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Paweł Fus for your suggestion on formatter.

I solved my problem by assigning date-format to formatter. Here is the code.

```
labels: {
                overflow: false,
                align: "center",
                style: _xaxis_label_style,
                step: _step,
                staggerLines: _staggerLines,
                x: 0,
                enabled: true,
                useHTML: term_useHTML,
                formatter: function () {
                    if ($j(".hdnSelection").val() == "today") {
                        return Highcharts.dateFormat(dateformatlable.hour, this.value);
                    }
                    else {
                        var key = "1month"; //default case
                        if (typeof $j('.hdnSelectionmonth') !== "undefined" && $j('.hdnSelectionmonth').val() != '') {
                            key = $j('.hdnSelectionmonth').val();
                        }
                        var duration = key.substring(1);
                        switch (duration.toLowerCase()) {
                            case "day":
                                return Highcharts.dateFormat(dateformatlable.day, this.value);

                            case "week":
                                return Highcharts.dateFormat(dateformatlable.week, this.value);

                            case "month":
                                return Highcharts.dateFormat(dateformatlable.month, this.value);

                            case "year":
                                return Highcharts.dateFormat(dateformatlable.year, this.value);
                                break;
                            case "ytd":
                                return Highcharts.dateFormat(dateformatlable.year, this.value);

                            default:
                                return Highcharts.dateFormat(dateformatlable.day, this.value);
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
showLastLabel: true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get selected unitName from tickPositionInfo and apply it in the label formatter:

```
xAxis: {
  type: 'datetime',
  labels: {
    formatter: function() {
      const format = {
        second: '%Y-%m-%d<br/>%H:%M:%S',
        minute: '%Y-%m-%d<br/>%H:%M',
        hour: '%Y-%m-%d<br/>%H:%M',
        day: '%Y<br/>%m-%d',
        week: '%Y<br/>%m-%d',
        month: '%Y-%m',
        year: '%Y'
      }[this.tickPositionInfo.unitName];
      return  Highcharts.dateFormat(format, this.value);
    }
  }
}
```